# ComboBox datasource: show complete item

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox, listcontrol

Suppose you have a fairly small sequence of Items where every Item has properties: Id and Name.
Id and Name are unique.
You want to show the items in a ListControl like a combo box.
You only want to show the Name of the Item, not the Id.
When the name of a displayed Item is selected, you want the Id of the Item as Selected Value:

This is easily done using a DataSource by setting properties DisplayMember and ValueMember

```
IList<Item> items = ...
this.ComboBox1.DataSource = items;
this.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(Item.Name);
this.ComboBox1.ValueMember = nameof(Item.Id)
```

When the item is selected:

```
int selectedId = (int) this.ComboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

And you can select an item by Id:

```
Item item = ...
this.ComboBox.SelectedValue = item.Id;
```

And presto, the name of the item is shown.

But now I have a sequence of items without properties, for instance an Enum:

```
IList<MyEnum> enums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().ToList();
this.comboBox1.DataSource = enums;
```

This is enough to display the enums in the combo box. No need to set DisplayMember / ValueMember.
I can get the selected enum:

```
MyEnum e = (MyEnum)this.ComboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

But I can't set it:

```
MyEnum e = ...
this.ComboBox1.SelectedValue = e;
```

Leads to exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember.'

So what should I set in ValueMember?

Comment: Use `SelectedItem = e`

Comment: My, is it that simple!

Answer (score 1):

CharlieFace came up with the following solution, and it worked:

```
private MyEnum SelectedEnum
{
    get => (MyEnum)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    set => this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = value;
}
```

In my example of a ComboBox that displays the Ids of Items:

```
private Item SelectedItem
{
    get => (Item)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    set => this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = value;
}
```

So even though only the Name of the item is shown; SelectedItem contains the complete Item of the DataSource.

Thanks CharlieFace!